# How to fill the white space left by caption in SCfigure with text

Tags: floats, sidecap

The `sidecap` package brings the `SCfigure` environment, which enables captions to be positioned to the left or the right of a `figure`.

I have a very long figure, ocuppying most of the `textheight`. I want my captions to appear by the figure. Both the caption and the figure span the with of the paper, so that text jumps from a place above the caption to another after the whole ensemble is gone.

The problem arises while trying to take advantage of the huge white area left by the caption, which is not as long as the figure. I want to get rid of it and force the text of the document to be typset there.

I have tried to mix  `minipage`, `wrapfigure` and `SCfigure`, with no success at all.
Below I provide a minimal working example that shows this white space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{SCfigure}[1][!h]
  \caption{The space above should be filled with text that skips the caption when it is reached.}
  \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight, width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{SCfigure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use just `minimpage`s within the figure and typeset the caption with `\captionof` rather than `\caption` (from `caption` or `capt-of`).

Comment: Could you provide an example? I can't figure it out. I have even had a look at `floatrow`, but still not working.

Comment: @cfr You should supply an example as answer.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Do you have any idea what I meant? Because I no longer do ....